# Laravel throws only one set of data from the Database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this code in Laravel but it only gives me one set of data although it should return many data.

[image]

this is what it returns to me

```
{
    "test": {
        "product_name": "Pineapple",
        "price": "50",
        "pricebook_promo_id": "no promo"
    }
}
```

when it should have been like this

```
{
    "test": {
        "product_name": "Pineapple",
        "price": "50",
        "pricebook_promo_id": "no promo"
    } , {
        "product_name": "Apple",
        "price": "45",
        "pricebook_promo_id": "1"
    } , {
        "product_name": "Banana",
        "price": "40",
        "pricebook_promo_id": "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: so, you are saying, they all belongs to same category ? could you show the original data from db ?

Comment: It's because you overwrite the array keys on every loop. You probably either meant to have the $result["test"] line at the bottom of the `foreach` e.g. `$result["test"][] = $json_output`, or similar.

Comment: @Ravi yes they're all fruits

Comment: @nyelnyelnyelnyelnyel go through all comments, *you overwrite the array keys on every loop.*

Comment: @JonStirling thanks mate you really helped me on this one 
such a rookie mistake for me

Comment: Use Eloquent ORM for the queries its much simplified  @nyelnyelnyelnyelnyel

Comment: @DENNISKITHINJI will it return back an output like the one that I need? sorry I have no idea mate. All this time I thought I was already using Eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `product_name`, `price` and `pricebook_promo_id` indexes in the array each iteration.

You should be doing `$json_output['product_name'][] = $product->product_name;`

Answer (score 0):

In your `foreach` loop you may use `$json_output` by this way:

```
$json_output[][
    'product_name' => $product->product_name,
    'price' => $product->price,
    'pricebook_promo_id' => ($product->product_promo == 0) ? 'no promo' : $product->product_promo,
];
```